# jQuery post DIV data from same class (div)

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I have a problem. i want to send some data to my iframe.php file.. 
data successfully submit but its only post first DIV data in iframe.php file..
Is there any good way to use jquery to submit multiple data with using same class? or if you give me alternative solution please give me..

I don't know jquery too much but little bit.

My Code HTML (DIV>

```
<div class='whois' data-website='1' data-ext='test'>Site 1</div> 
<div class='whois' data-website='2' data-ext='test'>Site 2</div> 
<div class='whois' data-website='3' data-ext='test'>Site 3</div> 
<span id="result"></span>
```

JQuery Code.

```
$(".whois").click(function() {

$('#result').html("Checking...");
//var div = $(".whois"); 

var $home = $('.whois');
var domain =$home.data('website');
  var search =$home.data('ext');

    var txt = $.ajax({

        type: "POST",

        url: "iframe.php",

        data: "domain="+ domain + "&search="+ search,

        success: function(data){

             $('#result').html(data);



        }

    });

return false;

});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map those values to an array like this:

```
var whoisData = $('.whois').map(function() {
     return { domain: $(this).data('website'), search: $(this).data('ext') };
}).get();

var txt = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "iframe.php",
    data: { data: whoisData },
    success: function(data){
         $('#result').html(data);
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle Map Example](http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/74vJV/)

Comment: But its show me wrong detail.. Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
undefined undefined
undefined undefined
undefined undefined
Source
undefined=undefined&undefined=undefined&undefined=undefined

Comment: data did not transfer to iframe.php i already tried $_REQUEST, $_POST with print_r();

Comment: See my edit, you should be able to do `$_POST["data"]` to get the array if I can remember my php syntax correctly (not likely!). If that's not working then there is something different with your HTML compared to the example you posted.

Comment: Yes your code work.. but i need to run this code when i click on div only send those div data which we clicked.. like i click on **SITE 1** DIV then its show only **Site 1** Data.. you could see my existed code.

Comment: In that case just change `var $home = $('.whois');` to `var $home = $(this);`. But that really wasn't what you were asking in your question.

Comment: Thanks.. Working :D actually i am from Pakistan and did not clearly explin.. Your provided code will help in my next projct.. i don't need to ask another queastion about jquery array problem....